# Не работает python в консоли. Ошибка: «"py" не является внутренней или внешней командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом»

Tags: python

Как окончил разработку страницы html, решил перенаправить её в Джанго, проблема в том, что Винда намертво не воспринимает python, хотя в path он есть, что может быть не так? К слову, питона у меня, выходит, что 3. 2 установил вручную, 1-ый в прошлом году, 2-ой сегодня при обновлении, а 3-ий это от PyCharm,я так понимаю, во всяком случае, я всех указал в ПУТЬ, но ничего не работает по-прежнему.

echo %path%

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Git\cmd;C:\gradle\gradle-8.3\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3\bin;;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\sqlite;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2023.3.3\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.3.3\bin;;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;
```

set path

```
set path
Path=C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Git\cmd;C:\gradle\gradle-8.3\bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Shell 8.0\bin\;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\bin;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.3\bin;;C:\src\flutter\bin;C:\Program Files\sqlite;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\WebStorm 2023.3.3\bin;;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2023.3.3\bin;;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32;C:\Users\OtterAndFinek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
```

Питон находится в %AppData%, в С-диске его нет(либо я его не заметил и в этом проблема, но проверял уже несколько раз.)

Пытался прописывать - py --version,

```
C:\Users\OtterAndFinek>py --version
"py" не является внутренней или внешней
командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.
```

когда я меняю запрос с py - на python, он без ошибки запускает новую строку и всё.

```
C:\Users\OtterAndFinek>python --version

C:\Users\OtterAndFinek>
```

Вот скриншот путей и скриншот папки с Питонами [image: path]

[image: папка]

Comment: Папку со скриптами - не добавлял, к слову.

Comment: Переменная `PATH` перечисляет **каталоги** в которых проводится поиск исполнимого файла. У вас вместо каталогов в неё вставлены пути к исполнимым **файлам**. Это раз. Что такое `py`? Такой штуки я не знаю. Это два. В пути должен быть только один Питон, иначе позже будут неприятности. Это три.

Comment: Решению не помогло, пока временное, что я придумал - скачать из майкрософт стора, завтра будем проверять. Если есть какие-то идеи, как исправить изначальную проблеу - буду рад.

Comment: py это экзешник который ставится в папку windows при установке питона ` для всех пользователей` . Он смотрит шебанг, сверяет версию питона с реестром и запускает нужный интерпретатор. Или что-то такое. Делает работу линуксового `env python`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

py это экзешник который ставится в папку windows при установке питона "для всех пользователей". Он смотрит шебанг, сверяет версию питона с реестром и запускает нужный интерпретатор. Или что-то такое. Делает работу линуксового env python

Документация на него

https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher

Чтоб он работал нужно установить любой от имени администратора.

Comment: Да, вроде как решилось. По-крайней мере, я переустановил Питон и поставил все рекомендации, включая ваши с правами, вроде всё заработало. Потом были проблемы с Джанго, но всё довольно быстро решилось, напрямую не надо было скачивать, а через консоль и pip. Топик можно закрывать, огромное спасибо всем.